# Pathfinding in Procedural cave generation

Tags: unity, c#, path-finding, procedural-generation

I'm learning [THIS](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/procedural-cave-generation-tutorial) tutorial about procedural cave generation using cellular automata with Unity.

I want to implement pathfinding on some enemies, so I need to make a quantization of the procedurally generated "non-wall" part of the map. Is there a best way to place nodes in this space?

I hope I was clear enough and I'm sorry if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial, just like any grid-based cave generation tutorial, will already generate both open and closed tiles. Thus you will already have a

> quantization of the procedurally generated "non-wall" part of the map

if you follow the tutorial through.